# Assign the half of the vector in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want to assign the half of the vector 1 and the rest o

```
df <- c("1","a","b","2")
[1] "1" "a" "b" "2"
```

Expected result

```
 [1] "1" "1" "0" "0"
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: I am curious about what you actually want to do. The solution using `rep` provided by others is great, but it has nothing to do with your original vector, is their any rules to assign 1 and 0 based on the original vector?

Comment: What half do you want to assign (change?) to 0? Just at random? Or certain items in the vector?

Comment: Please only use `dplyr`,`tidyr` tags if you use such packages in your question.

Comment: I saw you have accepted one of the answers. So what you want really has nothing to do with your original vector `c("1","a","b","2")`. The way you asked question is misleading. Next time, please ask relevant question with proper description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rep`

```
rep(1:0, each = length(df)/2, length.out = length(df))
#[1] 1 1 0 0
```

If it doesn't matter how 1's and 0's are assigned you could specify only `length.out`

```
rep(1:0, length.out = length(df))
#[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, slightly different way, would be:

```
'<-'(df, +(seq_along(df) <= length(df) %/% 2))
#df
#[1] 1 1 0 0
```